# -O3 loop increment optimization

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, critical-section

I have this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

long int global_variable;

struct process{
    long int loop_times_ = 0;
    bool op_;
    process(long int loop_times, bool op): loop_times_(loop_times), op_(op){}

    void run(){
        for(long int i=0; i<loop_times_; i++)
            if (op_) global_variable+=1;
            else global_variable-=1;
    }

};

int main(){
    struct process p1(10000000, true);
    struct process p2(10000000, false);

    std::thread t1(&process::run, p1);
    std::thread t2(&process::run, p2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout <<global_variable<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Main function fires up two threads that increment and decrement a global variable.
If i compile with this:

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp -lpthread
```

i get different output in each execution.
But if i add -O3 and compile with this:

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp -lpthread
```

the output is zero every time

What kind of optimization is happening here that eliminates my critical section, and how can i trick the compiler to not optimize it?

EDIT: OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4, g++: 5.4.0

Comment: You know this is undefined behavior, right?

Comment: The outcome of your current code can be calculated at compile time. Did you try to pass the number of iterations as 2 different arguments to the program and run it like this? ./a.out 10000000 10000000

Comment: I would expect that with the faster optimization, the first thread might even finish before the other one starts... Does in run extremely fast? Increase the number until it takes longer and see if the behavior reverts.

Comment: To see what optimizations are made, look at the generated machine code. Check the difference between the optimized and unoptimized versions.

Comment: @mrks The two outputs are the same with this change

Comment: @Baldrick i suspected so, and i changed to unsigned long numbers, and the outputs are the same. No matter how big the number is, the -O3 executes instantly

Comment: Then the code isn't actually looping - it's calculating the result in some smart way. I'd suspect he first thread is finishing instantly, incrementing the global by N, then the second thread is doing the same and decrementing it.

Comment: What compiler version are you using?  What OS?  Since it is undefined behavior those things will matter.  As you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ddfb83bc547491d) your example gives a different result on a different machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very likely that your run method is being optimized to the equivalent of:

```
 void run(){
      if (op_) global_variable += loop_times_;
            else global_variable -= loop_times_;
```

This is something the compiler can do quite easily with the information available.

To trick the compiler, you have to make sure that it's not obvious that the loop will add or subtract 1 *with no other side effects* on every iteration.

Try adding a function call into the loop, that just increments a simple counter on the object called `totalIterationsDone`, or some such. This might force the compiler into actually executing the loop. Passing in your loop variable as an argument might also force it to keep track of intermediate values of `i`.

```
struct process{
    long int loop_times_ = 0;
    bool op_;
    long int _iterationsDone = 0;
    process(long int loop_times, bool op): loop_times_(loop_times), op_(op){}

    void run(){
        for(long int i=0; i<loop_times_; i++){
            if (op_) global_variable+=1;
            else global_variable-=1;
            Trick(i);
        }
    }

    void Trick(int i){
       _iterationsDone += 1;
    }    
};
```

Comment: There are different outputs only when  i changed trick to take loop's i as an argument. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. That makes good sense actually. I'll edit my answer to match, with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has undefined behaviour, in the form of a data race. Two threads accessing one variable without synchronisation is a data race and thus undefined.

The easiest way to remove the data race would be to make `global_variable` atomic:

```
std::atomice<long int> global_variable;
```

No further changes should be necessary in the rest of the code.

Comment: But i don't want the data race to be eliminated. I just don't understand why the effects are not visible when the run is under -O3

Comment: @k_kaz **Undefined behaviour is undefined.** Nothing can be said about a program exhibiting UB - it could just as well order pizza online instead of working with a global var.

Comment: @k_kaz *Why* do you want the data race? Why do you want undefined behavior? You know that those are considered bad things?

Comment: @k_kaz: In production code, I'd agree. But in this case the OP is trying to understand what's going on under the hood out of interest. You can learn a lot from seeing what compilers generate, even in cases of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Of course i understand that this is a data race. I wrote the code just to generate this critical section. I just want to understand what the -O3 flag is doing in this situation

Comment: @k_kaz Then as I commented on your question, check the generated machine code. Disassemble the executable and see what it does.